# Blueimp multiple file upload

Tags: php, jquery-ui, codeigniter, file-upload, blueimp

I use a jQuery UI file uploader called Blueimp. It is a very nice stuff, working well with multiple files, but i just can't extract the file names this script has previously uploaded.

When i check the $_FILES array i can only see the last uploaded file.

When i try to check other members of the array like

```
$_FILES['userfile']['name'][1]
$_FILES['userfile']['name'][2]
```

I am getting back the characters that the filename consists of. Anyone knows why only the latest filename is available?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the  of type file as an HTML array like the following:

```
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" />
```